# runtime error while merging 2 binary trees

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++14, binary-tree

I'm trying to solve [merging binary trees](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-binary-trees/) problem from leetcode. Here is my c++ code

```
    class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {
        TreeNode *t;
        if(t1==nullptr){return t2;}
        if(t2==nullptr){return t1;}
        t->val=t1->val+t2->val;
        t->left=mergeTrees(t1->left,t2->left);
        t->right=mergeTrees(t1->right,t2->right);
        return t;
    }
};
```

This code is producing the following error

```
Line 18: Char 12: runtime error: member access within misaligned address 0x000000000001 for type 'TreeNode', which requires 8 byte alignment (solution.cpp)
0x000000000001: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:27:12
```

However if I tried to solve without using an extra TreeNode as shown below it's working fine

```
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {
        //TreeNode *t;
        if(t1==nullptr){return t2;}
        if(t2==nullptr){return t1;}
        t1->val=t1->val+t2->val;
        t1->left=mergeTrees(t1->left,t2->left);
        t1->right=mergeTrees(t1->right,t2->right);
        return t1;
    }
};
```

Can someone please explain why the first code is causing the error ?

Comment: Looks like we need the declaration and definition of the `TreeNode` `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Well, we'll need a [mcve] to be precise.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that link shows definition of TreeNode on right side

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy:  Sorry, but firewalls are preventing me from following links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code

```
TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {
    TreeNode *t;
    if(t1==nullptr){return t2;}
    if(t2==nullptr){return t1;}
    t->val=t1->val+t2->val;
```

`t` is an uninitialised pointer, and therefore `t->val` is an error.

Presumably you meant something like this

```
TreeNode* mergeTrees(TreeNode* t1, TreeNode* t2) {
    if(t1==nullptr){return t2;}
    if(t2==nullptr){return t1;}
    TreeNode *t = new TreeNode;
    t->val=t1->val+t2->val;
```

Answer (score 2):

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63818666/6553328) does address the issue.
- Yet we can still a bit simplify our statements here:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

static const struct Solution {
    TreeNode* mergeTrees(
        TreeNode* t1,
        TreeNode* t2
    ) {
        if (t1 && t2) {
            TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(t1->val + t2->val);
            root->left = mergeTrees(t1->left, t2->left);
            root->right = mergeTrees(t1->right, t2->right);
            return root;
        }
        
        return t1 ? t1 : t2;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing 't' as a pointer to a `TreeNode`, then you should add `t = new TreeNode;` after you wrote `TreeNode *t;`. Hope that will work :)